# Why doesn't calling a function from an object work in this for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

Edit: Problem solved, I forgot to put the output for the riteg object before.

Okay, so I'm quite sure how to describe this issue (which is why the title is bad), but this for loop:

```
function(){
            var out = 0;
            for(var i = 0;i<gameLists.listAllGen.length;i++){
                out += window[gameLists.listAllGen[i]].output();
            }
            return out/10000;
        },
```

doesn't work at all. In the console, it says: `TypeError: window[gameLists.listAllGen[i]].output is not a function`

When I replace the `[i]` with, for example, `[0]`, it works:

```
function(){
            var out = 0;
            for(var i = 0;i<gameLists.listAllGen.length;i++){
                out += window[gameLists.listAllGen[0]].output();
            }
            return out/10000;
        },
```

returns out as expected and no errors.

The variables if needed:

```
var gameLists = {
    listAllGen:['solarGen','riteg']
}
```

and

```
var solarGen = {
    name:"Solar Generator",
    count:0,
    genRate:0.25,
    price:410,
    output:
        function(){
            return this.count*this.genRate*10000;
        },
```

Comment: Does this help at all: http://jsbin.com/kabozi/1/edit?js,console

Comment: No, that was not a mistype. The strings are supposed to work with window, for example window[solarGen] returns an error, but window["solarGen"] does not.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9ad6kbfa/ does seem to work. Maybe you define your data in the wrong order?

Comment: I added the semicolons and it appears to be working as expected now (besides annoying floating point stuff). Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Doge - Where is the definition of `riteg`?

Comment: @haim770 - In your fiddle there is `[0]` in the for loop, this is the right and not working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9ad6kbfa/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gameLists.listAllGen[0] returns ->  solarGen
```

and you have `solarGen` in your script, thus `window[gameLists.listAllGen[0]].output()` referes to the output key and `()` calls the function assosiated with the key `solarGen`

But `gameLists.listAllGen[1]` return -> riteg

and no output property is assosiated with the riteg, thus it, and `window[gameLists.listAllGen[1]]` it expects. that there is riteg with output as a key aand a function assosiated with it, but it is not able to find that.

Thus you are getting the error

```
TypeError: window[gameLists.listAllGen[i]].output is not a function
```

because there is no function by that name.

Comment: After I posted this question I went ahead and looked at the riteg object and thought "hey, this needs an output function". I didn't even realise that I had solved the problem, and ended up mis-attributing the problem to a lack of semicolons (which as I understand, are not *strictly* necessary in JavaScript).